# Sharepoint Online/2016

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part, content-search-web-part, wiki-pages

Does anyone know how to display an image when using the "Search driven content" --> Wiki Pages Web Part? Ive tried messing with the "managed properties mapping" but nothing seems to work and I havent been able to find anything useful.

[image]